# how to mark the prescribed trajectory in gazebo simulation?

Tags: ros, world

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear,

I was able to make my simple model follow the prescribed position trajectory (circle or infinity shape or any smooth trajectory) in gazebo simulation. One more thing I want to do to show the prescribed trajectory in the gazebo simulation so that I want to show how closely my model follows the given trajectory. What part should I modify or edit ? Do I need to see the world file or look for different world file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12724/how-to-mark-the-prescribed-trajectory-in-gazebo-simulation-?/) by [maruchi](https://answers.ros.org/users/1429/maruchi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2012-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure it is easily possible to paint things into gazebo. For 3D visualization purposes, there is [rviz](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz) and [Markers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes) that can easily be used for this task. Having visualization outside of your simulation environment has the benefit that you can use it for simulation and for experiments with real robot systems. For this reason using the ROS visualization tools is the recommended way of doing what you describe.

If you want to record tf based trajectories, you can use the [hector_trajectory_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_trajectory_server) node. This node periodically publishes the trajectory as a [nav_msgs/Path](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html), which can be visualized in rviz.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1